# How to get this equation with integrals

Tags: analysis, stochastic-analysis

I don't understand how I get the following equation ($x\geq0$):
$$\int_0^xdy\int_y^{\infty}f(s)ds\int_{x-y}^{\infty}f(t)dt=\int\int_{s+t>x}(\min\{s,x\}-(x-t))f(s)f(t)dsdt$$

where $f$ is a density function of a postitive random variable, i.e. $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

By Fubini's theorem, $$\int_0^xdy\int_y^{\infty}f(s)ds\int_{x-y}^{\infty}f(t)dt=
\int\int\int_{0<y<x,s>y,t>x-y}f(s)f(t)dydsdt\\
=\int\int_{s+t>x, s>0,t>0}f(s)f(t)\int_{0<y<x,y<s,y>x-t}dy$$
Now if $x-t<0$, $$\int_{0<y<x,y<s,y>x-t}dy=\int_{0}^{\min(s,x)}dy=\min(s,x);$$
if $x-t\geq 0$, $$\int_{0<y<x,y<s,y>x-t}dy=\int_{x-t}^{\min(s,x)}dy=\min(s,x)-(x-t).$$
Thus the integral equals 
$$\int\int_{s+t>x,s>0,t>0}f(s)f(t)(\min(s,x)1_{x<t}+(\min(s,x)-(x-t))1_{x\geq t})dsdt\\=
\int\int_{s+t>x,s>0,t>0}f(s)f(t)(\min(s,x)-(x-t))dsdt\\
+\int\int_{s+t>x,s>0,t>0}f(s)f(t)(x-t)1_{x<t}dsdt\\=
\int\int_{s+t>x,s>0,t>0}f(s)f(t)(\min(s,x)-(x-t))dsdt\\
+\int\int_{t>x,s>0}f(s)f(t)(x-t)dsdt\\
=\int\int_{s+t>x}f(s)f(t)(\min(s,x)-(x-t))dsdt\\
+\int\int_{t>x,s>0}f(s)f(t)(x-t)dsdt.$$
This is different from the desired result. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: I saw this in a paper, so it should be. But your calculations seem to be correct. Thanks.